# Why do i get package this error in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter, so I am working on firebase authentication and have created a flutter firebase project but I am getting package errors when I run `flutter packages get`.

My Output looks like this

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS E:\new proj\firebase auth\firebase_auth_demo_flutter-master> flutter packages upgrade
Resolving dependencies...
Because every version of flutter_driver from sdk depends on test_api 0.3.0 and mockito >=4.1.2 <=5.0.0-nullsafety.7 depends on test_api ^0.2.19-nullsafety, flutter_driver from sdk is incompatible with mockito >=4.1.2 <=5.0.0-nullsafety.7.
So, because firebase_auth_demo_flutter depends on both flutter_driver any from sdk and mockito ^4.1.2, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 1
PS E:\new proj\firebase auth\firebase_auth_demo_flutter-master>
```

In my project my pubspec.yaml file looks like this

```
version: 0.2.0

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  apple_sign_in: ^0.1.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
  firebase_core: ^0.5.3
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.6.3
  flutter_login_facebook: ^0.4.0+1
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.5
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.6
  package_info: ^0.4.3+2
  provider: ^4.3.2+3
  random_string: ^2.1.0
  rxdart: ^0.25.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  mockito: ^4.1.2
  test: any

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message starting with "Because every version..." is actually very clear.

You need to increase the version of mockito that you use. You need to use a mockito version that depends on test_api 0.3.0 just like the Flutter SDK you're using does.

When two packages A and B depend on a single package C, there needs to be a version of C that both A and B can work with.

Comment: do you know when we put blank version  in pubspec.yaml file, what does it mean

Comment: It's explained here: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#version-constraints blank is the same as `any`. I'm not sure if it chooses a lower version for you, I haven't tried.